# does clients get an acknowledgement after a etcd leader replicate data to all other nodes?

Tags: etcd

Etcd cluster elects a leader under Raft consensus algorithm. When a client sends a write request to the leader, It should write a log in its disk and replicate it to other followers. I am unsure if the client gets an acknowledgment from a leader after all followers replicate the data or after N/2 + 1 nodes replicate the data.

For example, let's say that there are three nodes in the Etcd cluster. Does the client get an acknowledgment after a leader and a follower(two nodes in total) replicate the data? or after all three nodes successfully replicate the data?

If the latter is correct, does it mean that it has more latency when the Etcd cluster has more nodes because the client waits until all nodes replicate the data?

What happens if one of the followers takes too long or fails to replicate it?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something I've researched previously in [ETCD-14501](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/14501).

It requires N/2+1 acknowledgements before returning to the client.

> Does the client get an acknowledgment after a leader and a follower(two nodes in total) replicate the data?

Yes, exactly that.